# Sort the columns of a big Dataframe with different number of lines in ascending order

Tags: r

I have a short problem to sort the columns of a big dataframe, with different number of lines, in ascending order.

My dataframe in R is like this but much bigger:

```
 D          I        S       ...

 111       2012     1000
 111       2012     2000
 111       2012     1000
 111       2014     2000
 111       2013     1000
 111       2013     2000
```

I want to calculate how many factor levels there are for each factor and sort each column in descending order so the most important factor is in the first line, like this:

```
D     Count          I    Count           S    Count    ...

 111     6           2012      3          1000     3
                     2013      2          2000     3
                     2014      1
```

And now I want to sort the columns in ascending order so I get a a dataframe like this:

```
D     Count          S    Count           I    Count    ...

 111     6           1000      3          2012     3
                     2000      3          2013     2
                                          2014     1
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Is not clear how you want to sort the columns.Can you give more details on this?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, I would like to give you more details. The columns have a different numer of lines and I want to sort them in ascending order, so on the left is the shortest with just one line and on the right they getting bigger. I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: I see. Check the update in my the answer. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table` you can try the following. 
For the first part:

```
data_set <- read.table(header = TRUE, text='D   I   S
111 2012    1000
111 2012    2000
111 2012    1000
111 2014    2000
111 2013    1000
111 2013    2000')

library(data.table)
lst <- lapply(c("D","I","S"), function(x) setDT(data_set)[, 
                                          .(Count = .N), by = x][order(-Count)])
[[1]]
     D Count
1: 111     6

[[2]]
      I Count
1: 2012     3
2: 2013     2
3: 2014     1

[[3]]
      S Count
1: 1000     3
2: 2000     3
```

And for the second part you just

```
lst[order(sapply(lst,dim)[1,])]

[[1]]
     D Count
1: 111     6

[[2]]
      S Count
1: 1000     3
2: 2000     3

[[3]]
      I Count
1: 2012     3
2: 2013     2
3: 2014     1
```

Comment: For the first part it is perfect. Thank you very much! Do you have any idea for the 2nd part, too?

Comment: As I said, for that you need to provide details of what kind of sort you are looking for, cause as your question is now, it can be interpreted in many ways.

Comment: Wow, perfect! Just one little thing, I visual that as data.table in shiny and now I want to get after all the columns with count a bigger line or something to show that the count belongs to the left Factor level. Do you have an idea

Comment: Can you have a new question or provide what output you are looking for. I will try to help for sure.

Comment: Ok thanks, here I try to describe a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455693/r-shiny-datatable-column-split-with-line

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to sort the columns based on the number of unique instances per column? Then this might work (assuming your data frame is called df here):

```
ord <- order(sapply(df, function(col)length(unique(col))))
df[,ord]
```