# R shiny Datatable column split with line

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I generate a Datatable in my shiny server like:

```
x=renderTable(rownames = FALSE,{...}
```

And have a Ui like:

```
 tableOutput("x")
```

Now I want that every second column a split is marked as line. 
For example:

```
a   b | c   d | e  ...
1   2 | 2   3 | 4  ...
4   3 | 1   2 | 3  ...
3   1 | 5   5 | 5  ...
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used a subset of `mtcars` dataset to generate this output. Below is a self-sufficient reproducible example for the same. One has to use CSS Styling to achieve this effect. Additional Information for advanced Styling is available [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html)

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(datasets)


ui <- fluidPage(

  dataTableOutput("table")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  mtcars <- mtcars %>% select(1:8)
  row.names(mtcars) <- NULL

  output$table <- renderDataTable({

    # Initiate Empty Vector for Alternative border formating
    alt_vector <- vector(mode = "numeric")

    # Iterate over the no. of columns in the table to generate the vector
    for (i in 1:ncol(mtcars)) { 
      if(i %% 2 == 0) 
        alt_vector <- c(alt_vector,i)
    }

      df <- datatable(mtcars,rownames = FALSE, options = list(pageLength = 25)) %>%
            # First Column Border Left
            formatStyle(c(1),`border-left` = '1px solid black') %>% 
            # Rest Alternative Bordering
            formatStyle(alt_vector,`border-right` = '1px solid black')

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Attached is a snap-shot of the formatted table from the UI.

[image: A Snapshot from the UI generated from the code]

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help, it works. But I just want one page with all Data. How can I adjust that?

Comment: pageLength attribute can be used to achieve the same. Use 
**options = list(pageLength = nrow(mtcars))** as an argument in datatable creation.

Comment: Thanks, but this takes a long time, how can I just list this option and select the show 10 entries at fist? I tried: options = list(pageLength = nrow(result),selected = 10) but it doesnt work. Do you have an idea?

Comment: So,@Zorro do you want the output to look the same as the image that I posted in the answer ? With 10 rows per page ?

Comment: Yes, but also the option to select more than 100 because I have more data which takes a lot time to select first

Comment: Included the pageLength argument in the answer to 25 rows, but it can be changed as per need. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont get it. I want that the datatable show me 10 entiers first, but I can select the option to show me all data.

Comment: @Zorro I don't think there is a direct option exposed in DT to enable **dynamic pageLength**. I guess could try some JavaScript Callback to achieve this.

Comment: nice answer, is there a way to extend the separator into the header as well?